# What happens to other Auras on a Creature enchanted with bestowing, when the Creature dies?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

Case in point:

[Ill-Tempered Cyclops](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373545) has the Auras of (bestowed) [Thassa's Emissary](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?multiverseid=373735) and **Aqueous Form**.

Then the Cyclops changes zone (returned to library, hand, gets exiled or moved to graveyard by any means necessary).

Would I be correct to presume that the **Aqueous Form** goes to graveyard (like Auras do) and **Thassa's Emissary** stays on the battlefield as a creature (like Enchantment Creatures do)?

(Questionable interpretation being that the **Aqueous Form** stays on the "new" creature of **Thassa's Emissary**)

Comment: Roughly the same question as http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/questions/14243

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Aqueous Form goes to the graveyard.

It doesn't attach to the newly-a-creature Thassa's Emissary, because it wasn't enchanting Thassa's Emissary - it was enchanting the Cyclops, which has left the battlefield.

[Bestow](http://magiccards.info/rule/702-keyword-abilities.html#rule-702-102) comes with exceptions that let Thassa's Emissary simply become an Enchantment Creature once it's no longer attached, but there's nothing saying that it brings with it its formerly bestowed creature's auras.

Comment: Your main answer is right, but Bestow creatures don't actually leave and re-enter the battlefield when the creature they're enchanting leaves the battlefield. Rather, as the rules you linked to say, casting such a creature for the bestow cost creates a continuous effect that makes it an Enchantment - Aura until the creature it's attached to leaves the battlefield. When that happens, it simply stops being an Aura and reverts to being a creature, so the rule causing unattached auras to leave the battlefield simply does not apply.

Comment: @murgatroid99 Whoops, thanks for pointing that out - that was bad communication on my part, I certainly didn't mean to imply they actually left and came back.

Answer (score 0):

Aqueous Form goes to the graveyard.

> 704.5n If an Aura is attached to an illegal object or player, or is not attached to an object or player, that Aura is put into its owner's graveyard.

Thassa's Emissary becomes unattached and remains on the battlefield. (Note that it remains an Aura.)

> 702.102e If an Aura with bestow is attached to an illegal object or player, it becomes unattached. This is an exception to rule 704.5n.