# Losing Control of Bestowed Enchantment Creatures

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-bestow

I've been playing Magic for about six months and thought I had a decent handle on how things work until I ran into the following problem:

**Set-up:**
I was playing mono black devotion against blue-green control. I bestowed [Herald of Torment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Herald%20of%20Torment) onto [Pharika Chosen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pharika%20Chosen). At the end of my turn, my opponent (in control of [Prophet of Kruphix](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Prophet%20of%20Kruphix)) flashed in a [Siren of the Fanged Coast](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Siren%20of%20the%20Fanged%20Coast). I chose not to pay the tribute, so my opponent took my [Pharika Chosen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pharika%20Chosen) with [Herald of Torment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Herald%20of%20Torment) attached.

**Question:**
If I kill [Pharika Chosen](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Pharika%20Chosen) while my opponent controls it, when [Herald of Torment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Herald%20of%20Torment) becomes a creature again do I regain control of Herald of Torment, or does my opponent retain possession of it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [When I gain control of a creature, do I also gain control of any auras or equipment attached to it?](http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/q/14243/6692). I edited the title on the older one to hopefully prevent this question from being asked a third time.

Comment: "Could not pay the tribute"?  Did you mean "Chose not to pay the tribute", or do you think you need to move +1/+1 counters from other creatures or something?

Comment: My mana was tapped and I could not pay the tribute of 3.

Comment: @IlMatto0; Tribute does NOT mean what you think it does! The reminder text below the Tribute keyword clarifies this, but Tribute 3 means that your opponent can choose to have it enter the battlefield with 3 +1/+1 counters on it... NOT that your opponent can choose to pay 3 mana!

Comment: Thanks Gendolkari! Wow. My friend and I have been using it wrong for a long time. I feel dumb.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your opponent never had control of [Herald of Torment](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Herald%20of%20Torment). When he took your creature, he only took the creature; he did not take control of any auras (or equipment) attached to it. So in this case, he would have control of a creature that has an aura that you control on it. This means that the creature would have +3/+3 and flying like usual; and YOU would lose 1 life per turn, not him.

So when the Bestow falls off and becomes a creature, it will be a creature under your control. It always was under your control.